# is there isogenerator tool for ROS now

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, isogenerator to create ISO with ROS from wiki (http://wiki.ros.org/isogenerator) are out of service now. Code is not available from https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_release/trunk. Is there existing code on other uri? or is there any open sourced solution to build ISO with ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280089/is-there-isogenerator-tool-for-ros-now/) by [yechun](https://answers.ros.org/users/33227/yechun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe there is any specific tool to generate ISO images for ROS, but seeing as ROS is essentially deployed using a set of Debian packages onto an Ubuntu OS, you could probably follow just about any procedure to customise an Ubuntu LiveCD/USB.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yechun](https://answers.ros.org/users/33227/yechun/) on 2018-01-22**:
Thank you for your information.
Find the Ubuntu ISO native tools: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/InstallCDCustomizationHowTo, we need to customize by ourselves.